# Why are Gargeya and Bharadwaja Gotra distinct?

Tags: gotra

A question about Bhardwaja and Gargeya gotras.
Bhardwaja had two sons: Drona and Garaga (mother Kshatriya). Drona had one son "Ashwathama".
Ashwathana didn't have any sons. *So the entire Bhardwaja gotra descendants must be via Garaga?*

Why is then Garageya gotra separate from Bhardwaja?

Descendants of Bharadwaja are in the technical sense descendants of Gargeya. The question is why is there a distinction between Gargeya and Bharadwaja Gotra? What lead to this?

Comment: I have one possible explanation: assume the first generation of Gargeya descendants probably identified themselves as Bhardwajas (possibly because Bhardwaja was well known and Gargeya yet to gain fame). Later generations (at least some of them) idea themselves as Gargeya gotra. So imagine the eldest sons of Gargeya identified as Bhardwaja, where as younger ones identified themselves as Gargeya gotra

Comment: You r forgetting the complex episode of Vitatha / Bhumanyu.. from there also came many lineages of Bhardwaja..

Comment: @YDS Thats a good point, I recall something where the Bhumanyu or his one his descendants became a brhamin (belong to Bharadwaja clan) later? Is this right? Then that could the line of Bharadwajs as well?

Comment: yes @inpraiseofagni .. "Bhardwaja had two sons: Drona and Garaga (mother Kshatriya)" -- do u hv story source regarding how Garga was born? bdw, name of Vitatha's son was also Garga and this Garga had 4-5 brothers..

Comment: @YDS I dont know the story of Gargeya's birth. All I know is that he born to Bhardwaja and Kshetriya mother Sushela. Do you more info? Please do share

Comment: More info from Bhagvatam: Vitatha (Bharadvaja) had a son Manyu who begot 
(five sons) viz. Bfhatkfatra, Jaya, Mahavirya, Nara, Garga.   (Later):  From Garga was born Sini who begot Gargya. 
In this way, a Brahmana family-line started from a Ksatriya 
race. From Mahavirya sprang Duritaksaya whose sons were 
Trayyaruni, Kavi and Puskararurii. They attained to the 
state of Brahmanahood. Brhat-ksattra had a son, who built 
the city of Hastinapura.   source:https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205_djvu.txt

Comment: Another source: http://mahabharata-resources.org/bharata.html. The son of Vitatha (Bhardvaja) was Bhavanmanyu; his sons were many, and amongst them the chief were Vrihatkshatra, Mahaviryya, Nara, and Garga.  Now atleast according to Bhagvtam (Sri Pabhupada translation): Garga had son called Sini who had a son called Gargya, who then marks the founder of Gargeya gotra. So Bharadvaja gotra might have continued by all five sons of Manyu (except for Nara, who I think is progenitor of Mahabharata kings)

Comment: Yeah, i think now u got ur answers also from them.. u should self answer ur Q as u have got 2 references..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bhagavata and Vishnu Purana: Bharata requested Bharadvaja for a son as his he deemed his own progeny unfit to rule. Bharadvaja created "Bhumanyu" out of the sacrificial fire.

An alternate explanation is that "Bhumanyu" was child the Bharata and princess of Kasi.

Either which way, it appears that Bharadvaja presided the ritual of Bhumanyu being adopted by Bharata.

Bhumanyu had five sons: Bfhatkfatra, Jaya, Mahavirya, Nara, Garga. Nara's projeny continued to rule Bharata.

Now it appears that some of these five sons could have joined the Bharadvaja's ashrams to become rishis. These sons continued the lineage of Bharadvaja gotra.

One of the sons Garaga had a son called "Sini" who then had a son called "Gargya". "Gargya" was responsible for establishing the "Gargya" gotra.

In my opinion "Gargya" (son of Sini) could be the famous "Gargya Rishi" who named Krishna. I am basing this on the timelines.

I think there was adoption from Bharadvaja clan to the Bharata clan and peopel from Bharata clan becoming rishis under the Bharadvaja clan.

This lead to Bharadvaja and Gargeya gotra.

In Vedic times there was a Sanskrit convention for forming patronymics: if Garga was the father then Gargi was the son, Gargya the grandson and Gargy-yana the great-grandson.

I think in terms of timeline it makes sense that Gargya rishi was the one who named Krishna and is the progenitor of Gargya gotta.

*According to Pravara tradition:*

One belonging to Gaargya gotra would say:

> Abhivaadaye Aangirasa,(Baarhaspatya) (Bhaaradvaaja), Shainya, Gaargya thrayarsheya
> pravaraanvita Gaargya gothrah aapasthamba suthrah
> yajuhshaakhaadhyaayii shriiman {your name} sharmaanaamaaham asmi bhoh
> ||

So the lineage seems to be:
Aangirasa,(Baarhaspatya) (Bhaaradvaaja), Shainya, Gaargya according Pravara.

Sources:
[Bhagvata Purana - English Translation: Motilal](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205_djvu.txt)

[Bharata lineage - BORI](http://mahabharata-resources.org/bharata.html)